# facebook group page - add iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-group

My Facebook group is about my iPhone software. Is there a way to have it list all my iPhone apps with links/prices etc?

I noticed that this guy does it some how: http://www.facebook.com/AppStore

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That guy is most probably doing it on his own server and sending the resulting fbml/html to facebook to display on his apps home page.

Whether he is then querying the app store somehow to get the list of his apps, or is maintaining the list manually I don't know. Not aware of a way to get that from the app store, but that isn't saying much, as I've never looked!